# Is there a risk of rot with plastic lining in a raised garden bed?

Tags: raised-beds, drainage

I'm considering lining the walls (not the bottom) of my soon to be raised garden bed with some heavy/medium duty plastic. I've read that this helps the wood last longer by preventing contact with the moist soil.

My one concern is that if water/moisture of some kind got between the wood and the lining. Wouldn't this be pretty bad?

Is there any risk of lining the walls of my garden be with plastic?

Answer (score 3):

When (not if) water gets between the plastic and the lining, it will move through the wood to the outside of the bed and evaporate. If the wood is rot resistant, this should not be a problem (certainly no more of a problem than direct ground contact exposure to damp soils.)

Comment: Thanks. I'm using cedar wood which I've heard is rot resistant.

Comment: Hey. I've got the lining up and it just rained and there's water trapped between the lining and the wood. Just wondering how long you think it will stay there, because it doesn't seem to be moving through the wood and dissipating.  This is before I've put the soil in.